# Updating a database while using a preparedStatement select

Tags: java, prepared-statement

I'm selecting a subset of data from a MS SQL datbase, using a `PreparedStatement`.
While iterating through the resultset, I also want to update the rows. At the moment I use something like this:

```
prepStatement = con.prepareStatement(
                    selectQuery,
                    ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,
                    ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);


 rs = prepStatement.executeQuery();

while(rs.next){
rs.updateInt("number", 20)
rs.updateRow();
}
```

The database is updated with the correct values, but I get the following exception:

```
Optimistic concurrency check failed. The row was modified outside of this cursor.
```

I've Googled it, but haven't been able to find any help on the issue.

How do I prevent this exception? Or since the program does do what I want it to do, can I just ignore it?

Comment: Can your tell us which transaction isolation level is in use?

Comment: ... and also what the exact query and exact column you updateInt?

Answer (score 2):

The record has been modified between the moment it was retrieved from the database (through your cursor) and the moment when you attempted to save it back.  If the `number` column can be safely updated independently of the rest of the record *or* independently of some other process having already set the `number` column to some other value, you could be tempted to do:

```
con.execute("update table set number = 20 where id=" & rs("id") )
```

However, **the race condition persists**, and your change may be in turn overwritten by another process.

The best strategy is to **ignore the exception** (the record was not updated), possibly pushing the failed record to a queue (in memory), **then do a second pass** over the failed records (re-evaluating the conditions in `query` and updating as appropriate - add `number <> 20` as one of the conditions in `query` if this is not already the case.)  Repeat until no more records fail.  Eventually all records will be updated.

Comment: Could it be that "the someone else" who is triggering the optimisitic lock exception on your side has actually performed the update that you are seeing? :)

Comment: Nope, the update only happens in one place, my process is the only one accessing the database

Comment: Aha! This can only mean that your query is returning duplicate records, updates fine the first time, fails the second time. :)  Why would this be the case?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know exactly which rows you will update, I would do

- SET your AUTOCOMMIT to OFF
- SET ISOLATION Level to SERIALIZABLE
- SELECT row1, row1 FROM table WHERE somecondition FOR UPDATE
- UPDATE the rows
- COMMIT

This is achieved via pessimistic locking (and assuming row locking is supported in your DB, it should work)